# Issue with activating virtual environment through batch file

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, virtual-environment

I am trying to activate a virtual environment using a batch file in Windows, but it isn't working. This is the script that I'm using:

```bash
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Activating the virtual environment
ECHO ===================================
ECHO current directory: %CD%
ECHO ====================================
CALL %CD%\virt_test\Scripts\activate
ECHO current directory: %CD%
ECHO ====================================
ECHO Check activation virtual environment
python VerifyVirtEnv.py
```

and here `VerifyVirtEnv.py` verifies whether the virtual environment has been activated using `sys.prefix` and `sys.base_prefix`.

Activating the virtual environment does work directly from `powershell`, but why isn't it working like this?